# check variables and dates and mutate result as 1 or 0 grouped by id

Tags: r

```
DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),code=c("AA","BB","AA","DD","EE","FF"),date=c("2001-01-01","NA","2005-05-05","2006-06-06","2007-07-07","NA"),date2=c("2000-12-20","2000-12-20","2000-12-20","2000-12-20","2000-12-20","2000-12-20"))

DF

  id code       date      date2
1  1   AA 2001-01-01 2000-12-20
2  1   BB         NA 2000-12-20
3  2   AA 2005-05-05 2000-12-20
4  2   DD 2006-06-06 2000-12-20
5  3   EE 2007-07-07 2000-12-20
6  3   FF         NA 2000-12-20

VAR=c("AA","HH","KK")
```

Desired output:

```
  id code       date      date2 var
1  1   AA 2001-01-01 2000-12-20   1
2  1   BB         NA 2000-12-20   1
3  2   AA 2005-05-05 2000-12-20   0
4  2   DD 2006-06-06 2000-12-20   0
5  3   EE 2007-07-07 2000-12-20   0
6  3   FF         NA 2000-12-20   0
```

I want to check if any of the variables in `VAR` matches with `code`. If true then I want to check that `date` is max 30 days older than `date2` - if that also is true it should result in 1 in `var`. Everything should ge grouped by `id`.

Thanks in advance

Best H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  mutate_at(vars(date, date2), as.Date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(var = +(any(code %in% VAR) & (is.na(date) | (date - date2) < 30))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      id code  date       date2        var
#   <dbl> <chr> <date>     <date>     <int>
# 1     1 AA    2001-01-01 2000-12-20     1
# 2     1 BB    NA         2000-12-20     1
# 3     2 AA    2005-05-05 2000-12-20     0
# 4     2 DD    2006-06-06 2000-12-20     0
# 5     3 EE    2007-07-07 2000-12-20     0
# 6     3 FF    NA         2000-12-20     0
```